# Avoid CORS preflight OPTIONS for better performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, cors

Working with a CDN provider and calling static HTML files from CDN like this.

```
          $.ajax({
            url : CDNPATH,
            type : "GET",
            contentType : "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
            async : async,
            cache : true,
            processData : false,
            success : function(response, status, xhr) {
                onSuccess(response, status, xhr);
                $(document).trigger('contentReady');
            }
        });
```

On the homepage of the application, I have 5 static HTML files which fires 5 OPTION calls. As you can imagine, it hurts the performance. I have seen on similar questions that it can be avoided with `GET` methods and `text/plain`, which I did as above but it didn't work.

How can I avoid these preflight OPTIONS methods?

Comment: Do you exactly what request headers your browser is sending? Can you add them to the question?

Comment: A simple GET with only approved request and response headers should avoid an OPTIONS request. (I just proved it to myself to be sure.) I've just checked using exactly your `$.ajax` call with jQuery v3.1.1 and it didn't trigger a preflight, so I'm thinking it may be a response header from your CDN that's making it necessary... (BTW: You don't need `contentType`, you're not sending data to the server.)

Comment: I remain curious about trying to find out what’s triggering the preflight here, but without being able to see the exact request headers the client-side code is ultimately sending in the request, we’re just playing a guessing game.

Comment: would you mind checking out the domain if I post it here? @sideshowbarker

Comment: @DarthVader Yeah happy to help if you have more information to post—and I’m sure others here are too

Comment: @DarthVader Thanks—so I see `X-TS-AJAX-Request` in the request headers. That’s what’s triggering the browser to do the OPTIONS requests.

Comment: @DarthVader: That information should be **in the question**, not off-site. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the presence of the `charset` param is causing the preflight? Per-spec, browsers are [required to ignore any params and only consider the MIME type](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header), but maybe they’re not conforming.

> A CORS-safelisted request-header is a header whose name is one of
>
> - `Accept`
> - `Accept-Language`
> - `Content-Language`
> - `Content-Type` and whose value, once parsed, has a MIME type (ignoring parameters) that is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain`

Elsewise I don’t see what in your request would trigger a preflight. Maybe I’m missing something…

---

#### Update 2017-02-20

OK based on [information provided in a comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42313665/avoid-cors-preflight-options-for-better-performance/42313842?noredirect=1#comment71828635_42313665) it seems the source for the site contains a `script` element with this content:

```javascript
window["_tsbp_"] = { ba : "X-TS-BP-Action", bh : "X-TS-AJAX-Request"};
```

…and I’ve not stepped through the rest of the code to see what effect that has, but it appears to be causing an `X-TS-AJAX-Request` header to get added to XHR requests, triggering the preflight.

---

I guess the general takeaway here is: whenever you find that a request is triggering a browser to do a preflight but you don’t know why, troubleshooting step number should probably be to use your browser devtools to find out exactly what request headers your code is causing to get sent out.

Comment: I tried exactly the OP's `$.ajax` call (including `charset`) with a cross-origin request locally. Didn't trigger OPTIONS. Adding an unapproved header did. So I'm wondering if it's a response header from the CDN, but...

Comment: I removed the charset from contentType and still seeing OPTIONS method:(

Comment: Browsers evaluate the need for a preflight based just on the headers that are set by the client-side code. So a header added by the CDN wouldn’t trigger a preflight, as far as I can see. Must be something else.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I realize now that you must have meant the CDN was injecting the header into the client-side code the browser runs. At least that seems to be what’s happening here with the X-TS-AJAX-Request header that gets added.

Comment: @sideshowbarker: I didn't mean that, no. I can't see how the CDN could be modifying the browser code. Sounds like a browser extension or `ajaxStart` handler adding headers in the OP's code.

Comment: Ah OK yeah that would make more sense